# iOS block becoming zombie

Tags: ios

I have passed method as block and my function is like this.

```
- (void)setPhoneNumber:(NSString *)phoneNo andView:(UIView *)view andSuccessBlock:(void (^)(id responseObject))successBlock andFailureBlock:(void (^)(NSString *errorMsg, NSInteger errorCode, AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failureBlock {

}
```

I call like this.

```
    [[WSHelper sharedInstance] setPhoneNumber:phoneNumber andView:nil andSuccessBlock:^(id responseObject) {

    } andFailureBlock:^(NSString *errorMsg, NSInteger errorCode, AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    }];
```

Problem is that when I check successBlock, it is released (I am using arc and should not release like that). I have tried typedef and also not okay. In my other projects, this is working fine but only here, it is not okay. How can I solve?

> (lldb) po successBlock  
>   0x00000001078063c0

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added the code within the blocks. But I'm wondering if something in there is causing a circular reference. I would try allocation profiling the app with logging of all retains turned on. That will show you where the retains are occurring, which (with a bit of luck) will indicate what the problem is.