# iOS object/ becoming zombie

Tags: ios

I have written very simple block like this.

```
void (^successblock)() = ^(id responseObject) {

};
//here with breakpoint, I call successBlock
```

Then, in next line after this, when I 'po', it become zombie object :O (0x3433053953). In other project, it is okay. Only one of my project got issue. Is there something that I need to check? (like arc, etc). My project is arc though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS block becoming zombie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761178/ios-block-becoming-zombie)

Comment: Can you add complete code?

Comment: sorry. it is complete code. I think code is okay..project setting might got issue. My very simple block become zombie after declare. 